# Ionic call intent doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, android-intent, ionic-framework

Greatings!

I'm trying to send a direct intent like this

```
<a href="tel:1699999999">Click me!</a> //brazilian number
```

but when I click on the link, nothing happens!

I already installed the "whitelist-plugin" and added

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

to my config.xml. I'm using the latest versions of IONIC and CORDOVA by npm.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've accomplished this without having to use the allow-intent tag. In my case, it was a matter of formatting the telephone number before putting it in the href.

config.xml

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="tel:*" />
```

HTML

```
<a href="tel:555-555-5555">Call Location</a>
```

If your phone number is coming through dynamically, you can format it within your controller and render out the scope variable

HTML

```
<a href="tel:{{formattedPhone}}">Call Location</a>
```

Comment: After installing Ionic on another computer and pulling the project, I had to reinstall some plugins, like whitelist.

After that, the href simple worked, without a formatted number (like 555555555).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/05/01/example-of-intents-with-phonegap/

Usage example:

```
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity({ 
    action: WebIntent.ACTION_CALL,
    type: 'text/plain', 
    url: tel
  }, 
  function() {}, 
  function() { alert('Failed!'); }
);
```